# How can I print the Irq handler function name from idt table?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt

For background, I managed to print my IDT Table with my kernel module. It will show me the irq number, Stub Address, Segment, DPL, Type, and Handler Name. But unfortunately, my handler name always return the stub of the address not the actual handlers name.

For example, for irq number 34 it will return

```
34     0xffffffffa6600180  10            0     Interrupt gate     irq_entries_start+0x10/0x660
```

I believe irq number 34 is for handling nvme irq, as I look it up on `proc/interrupts`. But it wont return like nvme_irq or nvme_irq_handler or something like that show me the irq_handler function. How I can show the actual handler name of the idt table using the address?
If you interested to look my github source code for checking the idt table, here is the GitHub link: [GitHub Check IDT Repo](https://github.com/hansenidden18/checkidt/tree/master).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a way to print it, by using `irq_to_desc()` function. It will return the irq desc and then I get the `action->handler` address. Then, I call sprint_symbol on the address, which returns its handler name. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `char *name = symbol_lookup(address);` to obtain the name of the function instead of `sprint_symbol`

Comment: After I looked in the linux source code, the symbol_lookup uses kalsyms_lookup_name function, which I already tried and the result will be just irq_entries_start not the actual irq handler.